# Get minus (-)double value upto 6 point

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using double up to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554569/using-double-up-to-two-decimal-places)

Hi i want to convert double  value upto 6 point something like if value is

```
  -1.00005522000
```

it should be converted and resulted into

```
  -1.000055
```

i know there are lots of solution but still i could not getting the value

if i use value like

```
  : -1.79769313486231E308
```

the resulted value become

```
  -9.22337203668547
```

i have used reference like

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/RoundTwoDecimalPlaces.shtml

[How to print upto two decimal places in java using string builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528904/how-to-print-upto-two-decimal-places-in-java-using-string-builder)

[Using double up to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554569/using-double-up-to-two-decimal-places)

but do not get solution so please any body can help me?

Comment: Well done for rejecting the first link, but the third one contains the answer.

Answer (score 6):

use decimal format.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
df.format(1.00005522000);
```

for more information click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
txtAlt.setText(df.format(getInfo.getDoubleExtra("alt", 0))); but still get 09-10 12:36:44.199: I/System.out(3611): Double Value is : -179769313486231000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 3):

```
double d = 1.00005522000;
String result = String.format("%.6f", d);
```

Comment: I have used this way also but do not know still not getting value

Comment: Do you want to format your double value to 6 decimal points as a String, or do you want a double value that is the result of rounding another double? If you want the latter, then you should use something like `BigDecimal`. A `double` generally cannot represent any specific fractional number exactly. (A number that terminates in base 10 often does not terminate in base 2.)

Answer (score -1):

```
string str=1.00005522000;
sting[] newstr=str.split(".");
newstr[0];//contains 1
newstr[1];//contains 00005522000
newstr[1].substring[0,5];//it contains  6 numbers
```

Comment: The OP wants to convert from a double, not a string. Not an answer.